# Pandas data frame how to make a scatter plot for clustering a list of values into a set of groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this pandas df with 2 columns

```
     target                        drugs

0   ACE2 gene                [angiotensin II,rosiglitazone,irbesartan,valsar]
1   Elastases                [heparin,prednisolone,montelukast,formoterol]
2   MAPK14 protein           [oxaprozin,nilotinib,imatinib,tocilizumab]
3   TMPRSS2 gene             [enzalutamide,camostat]
4   Toll-like receptors      [rituximab,atorvastatin,artesunate,tazarotene]
5   Ubiquitin                [sunitinib,lapatinib,atorvastatin,edaravone]
6   ezrin                    [erlotinib,crizotinib,sorafenib,everolimus]
```

and I want to create a plot that clusters the drugs into their target, so there will be 7 clusters (7 targets) , I am not sure how to do it..

This is the df:

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = {'target': ['ACE2 gene', 'Elastases', 'MAPK14 protein, human', 'TMPRSS2 gene', 'Toll-like receptors', 'Ubiquitin' , 'ezrin'],'drugs': [['angiotensin II','rosiglitazone','irbesartan'], ['heparin','prednisolone','montelukast','formoterol'] , ['oxaprozin','nilotinib','imatinib','tocilizumab'] , ['enzalutamide','camostat'] , ['rituximab','atorvastatin','artesunate','tazarotene'] , ['sunitinib','lapatinib','atorvastatin','edaravone'], ['erlotinib','crizotinib','sorafenib','everolimus']]
}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot `scatterplot` with `seaborn` like below: *(Because you say in the comments of other answer, You have problem with answer, I send **another answer with another approach**.)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
import seaborn as sns
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'target': ['ACE2 gene', 'Elastases', 'MAPK14 protein, human', 'TMPRSS2 gene', 'Toll-like receptors', 'Ubiquitin' , 'ezrin'],
                          'drugs': [['angiotensin II','rosiglitazone','irbesartan'], ['heparin','prednisolone','montelukast','formoterol'] , 
                                    ['oxaprozin','nilotinib','imatinib','tocilizumab'] , ['enzalutamide','camostat'] , 
                                    ['rituximab','atorvastatin','artesunate','tazarotene'] , ['sunitinib','lapatinib','atorvastatin','edaravone'], 
                                    ['erlotinib','crizotinib','sorafenib','everolimus']]})

df['times'] = df['drugs'].apply(lambda x : len(x))
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['times'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df['drug'] = df.groupby('target')['drugs'].transform(lambda x: list(y[idx] for idx, y in enumerate(x)))
df = df.drop(['drugs','times'], axis=1)
df['unq_id'] = df.index+1


fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
axe.axis('off')
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="unq_id", y="target", hue="target", ax= axe, s=1000)
for _, point in df.iterrows():
  axe.text(point['unq_id']-0.2, point['target'], point['drug'], rotation=45, size=18)

plt.setp(axe.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='22') # for legend text
plt.setp(axe.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='32') # for legend title
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You can use `networkX` like below:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'target': ['ACE2 gene', 'Elastases', 'MAPK14 protein, human', 'TMPRSS2 gene', 'Toll-like receptors', 'Ubiquitin' , 'ezrin'],
                          'drugs': [['angiotensin II','rosiglitazone','irbesartan'], ['heparin','prednisolone','montelukast','formoterol'] , 
                                    ['oxaprozin','nilotinib','imatinib','tocilizumab'] , ['enzalutamide','camostat'] , 
                                    ['rituximab','atorvastatin','artesunate','tazarotene'] , ['sunitinib','lapatinib','atorvastatin','edaravone'], 
                                    ['erlotinib','crizotinib','sorafenib','everolimus']]})


df['times'] = df['drugs'].apply(lambda x : len(x))
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['times'])].reset_index(drop=True)
df['drug'] = df.groupby('target')['drugs'].transform(lambda x: list(y[idx] for idx, y in enumerate(x)))
df= df.drop(['drugs','times'], axis=1)

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(set(chain.from_iterable(df.values)))
for edg in df.values:
    g.add_edge(*edg)
pos = graphviz_layout(g, prog="dot")

fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,10))
nx.draw(g, pos,with_labels=True, node_shape='s', ax = axe)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I get this error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path.`  (I use Jupyter notebook btw - I think there is an issue with the installation of pydot or graphviz)

Comment: @Electra welcome, please check code here : https://colab.research.google.com/, I don't get any error

Comment: I think it's the wrong link? I cannot find the code there

Comment: @Electra please add cell for code and copy code and run this

Comment: I did that but I get the same error.. I think it's a configuration issue of the module pydot

Comment: I have tried to fix the error with the pydot module but it's quite complex and it doesn't serve the purpose of the exercise since you need to install also the application Graphviz and change some system variables etc and this is an assignment that I have to send to another user, so it has to be smt simper than that.. If there is a simpler way to make this into a graph it would be great

Comment: @Electra OK, I will send another answer until one hour later

Comment: @Electra I send another answer, Is this help you?